# get rxjs subscription data once and reuse data later

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, rxjs

Currently, I'm getting plans from a service using RxJS:

```
public class PlansListComponent implements OnInit {
private plans$: Subject<PlanDTO> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

ngOnInit():void {
    this.serverService
        .list()
        .subscribe(
            (plans: Array<PlanDTO>) => {
                this.plans$.next(
                    (plan) => plan
                );
            },
            (error: any) => {

            }
        );
}
```

where `PlanDTO` is:

```
{
    id: plan.id,
    name: plan.name,
    trial: plan.trial
}
```

So, I'm consuming `plans$` using two-way binding with `async`: `[data]="plans$ | async"`.

Up to now, everything works fine. Nevertheless, I need to handle with these plans I've just got from server.

I'm listing plans on a table where I let user selects "trial" plans. I don't quite to figure out once the subscription has been completed, how can I filter previously downloaded plans. I'm only be able to think about using `plans$` again, nevertheless that's going to download plans from again, isn't it?

```
public filterTrialPlans(): void {
    // how can I use this.plans$ again without request data from server again?
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm building an Angular2 application. Currently I'm engaged on building a "page" which has 3 angular2 components:

- `PlansComponent` Main Plans component.

  - `PlansList` component -> list all plans.
  - `PlanForm` component -> create a new plan.

I'm swaping "child" components using this code:

```
<div *ngIf="plansListShow" plans-list [planType]="currentPlanType" (onPlanOpen)="planOpen($event)" class="col-lg-9 col-xl-10 col-xs-12"></div>
<div *ngIf="planFormShow" plan-form (backToPlanList)="changePlanComponent('planList')" class="col-lg-9 col-xl-10 col-xs-12"></div>
```

where `plansListShow` and `planFormShow` are `PlansComponent` properties.

The component intended to get all plans from server is `PlansList`. In order to get them I'm using code exposed above, using a `BehaviorSubject plans$`.

The main goal of this component is list all plans and according to the user interaction with this list, the component can perform several actions:

```
toggleAll(checked: boolean): void {
    for (let plan of this.plans) {
      plan.selected = checked;
    }

    this.$toggleAll.prop('checked', checked);
  }

  deleteSelectedPlans(): void {
    let plans = [];
    this.plans.forEach((plan) => {
      if (!plan.selected) {
        plans.push(plan);
      }
    });
    this.serverservice.deletePlans(plans);
  }
```

I think that there are two options in order to refer plans:

1. Download then once and push them on a local `plans` field.
2. Use the `BehaviorSubject` every time -> question: is it cached?

Comment: since `plans$` is already a `BehaviorSubject` just use something like `this.plans$.subscribe(...)` .. it will just replay the last plans again - have you tried that yet?

Comment: This is exactly what I want to avoid. I don't want to replay (download) all plans every time I need them. I don't know if I've explained so well.

Comment: If you just subscribe to `plan$` nothing will be dowloaded, the `BehaviorSubject` has the latest value cached - but maybe you can update your question with information what data you want to show when& where, I have a suspicion that an rxjs chain might be what you are looking for (though it is unclear from your current question)

Comment: Thanks @olsn I've tried get you some details... I don't know if they're going to help you... Nevertheless, I'm going to take a look at rxjs chains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use either way - technically speaking both should work - though if you want to go by the *"rxjs-book"* you should use the `BehaviorSubject`, it **does** cache the latest value.

If you want to use only a subset of the plans, you then could simply chain an operator:

```
public trialPlans$ = this.plans$.filter(plan => plan.isTrial);
```

and then use it with `tialPlans$ | async` like you do with `plans$`.

---

If you want to do it **really well**, you should have a look at [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/store) - a store-concept, that focuses completely on the challenges that you are currently experiences - however this will require some code-refactoring.

Comment: Thanks a lot @osln. Awesome!